# Problem installing raster package for R 4.2.1 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: r, ubuntu-20.04, r-raster

I'm attempting to install the raster package to be able to run a model in RStudio - I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, and R 4.2.1. Whenever I run `install.packages('raster')` in the RStudio console I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmhBZ.png). I've already installed r-cran-raster for Ubuntu, am using a PPA, and have tried downloading the raster package to manually install.

I am relatively new to R and Ubuntu, so would appreciate any suggestions for what to try!

error message from `install.packages('raster')`:

```
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
in method for ‘brick’ with signature ‘x="kasc"’: no definition for class “kasc”
in method for ‘brick’ with signature ‘x="grf"’: no definition for class “grf”
in method for ‘coerce’ with signature ‘"STFDF","RasterBrick"’: no definition for class “STFDF”
in method for ‘coerce’ with signature ‘"STSDF","RasterBrick"’: no definition for class “STSDF”
in method for ‘coerce’ with signature ‘"asc","RasterLayer"’: no definition for class “asc”
in method for ‘coerce’ with signature ‘"RasterLayer","asc"’: no definition for class “asc”
in method for ‘coerce’ with signature ‘"kasc","RasterBrick"’: no definition for class “kasc”
in method for ‘coerce’ with signature ‘"kasc","RasterStack"’: no definition for class “kasc”
in method for ‘coerce’ with signature ‘"kde","RasterLayer"’: no definition for class “kde”
in method for ‘coerce’ with signature ‘"grf","RasterBrick"’: no definition for class “grf”
in method for ‘coerce’ with signature ‘"grf","RasterLayer"’: no definition for class “grf”
in method for ‘extent’ with signature ‘x="bbox"’: no definition for class “bbox”
in method for ‘extent’ with signature ‘x="sf"’: no definition for class “sf”
in method for ‘extract’ with signature ‘x="Raster",y="sf"’: no definition for class “sf”
in method for ‘mask’ with signature ‘x="Raster",mask="sf"’: no definition for class “sf”
in method for ‘raster’ with signature ‘x="sf"’: no definition for class “sf”
in method for ‘raster’ with signature ‘x="kasc"’: no definition for class “kasc”
in method for ‘raster’ with signature ‘x="asc"’: no definition for class “asc”
in method for ‘raster’ with signature ‘x="kde"’: no definition for class “kde”
in method for ‘raster’ with signature ‘x="grf"’: no definition for class “grf”
in method for ‘rasterize’ with signature ‘x="sf",y="Raster"’: no definition for class “sf”
Creating a generic function for ‘rowSums’ from package ‘base’ in package ‘raster’
Creating a generic function for ‘colSums’ from package ‘base’ in package ‘raster’
in method for ‘setValues’ with signature ‘x="RasterLayerSparse"’: no definition for class “RasterLayerSparse”
in method for ‘stack’ with signature ‘x="kasc"’: no definition for class “kasc”
munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘raster’
* removing ‘/home/emmsage/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/raster’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘raster’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpuqJnA5/downloaded_packages’
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package **raster** depends on **terra**, which has system requirement on external libraries.

[image: raster]

[image: terra]

---

On Ubuntu 20.04, do the following.

Install **GEOS**

```
# Add the Ubuntu GIS PPA
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa

## update cache
sudo apt-get update

# Install the packages
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common geos
```

Install **GDAL**

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev gdal-bin libgdal-dev
```

Install **PROJ**

```
sudo apt-get install proj-bin
```

Install **sqlite3**

```
sudo apt install sqlite3
```

Only after these, can you do `install.packages("raster")` in **R**.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @Zheyuan is very good and complete and detailed, and utilises the existing Ubuntu binaries -- and appropriate PPAs -- well.

But more recently, a new choice became available via the [r2u](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u/) setup I created.  It is very similar, but offers *all* of CRAN as binaries for Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04.  Myself and a few other already use it quite extensively.

I recorded a quick animated gif to show it which [I will post at Twitter](https://twitter.com/eddelbuettel/status/1546660676566925314) in a reference to this answer (I cannot post gifs over 2mb here, hence the detour). I use Docker here to simulate an "empty" system with R and not much else under 20.04 "focal".  The [r2u](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u/) has the setup steps you would need to make in a simple script you can exmine and carefully run its five steps.

Once done, you get `install.packages("raster")` to give you *all the binaries* in one step.  (In the video I also tell my computer the local address of the server.  That is only needed here and not generally.)